# Jakarta EE9 dependency for javax.portlet

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am trying to replace javax references to jakarta in my project as per the Jakarta EE9 standard. The problem is I am unable to find a jakarta dependency for

```
javax.portlet:portlet-api
```

In this jar there is an interface **PortletRequest**, of which I am using the method

```
 public javax.servlet.http.Cookie[] getCookies();
```

So I need a dependency which might have this method as

```
 public jakarta.servlet.http.Cookie[] getCookies();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `jakarta.servlet.http.Cookie` class is present in the following artifact:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>${jakarta.servlet-api.version}</version>
</dependency>
```